# Azure APIM inbound JWT validation policy works for GET and not for POST

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have written below Azure APIM policy which validates JWT Token, it works fine for GET, but not for POST. How can i resolve this issue ?

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/0000000000000000000/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>00000000000</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/0000000000000000/</issuer>
            </issuers>
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud">
                    <value>00000000000000000000000</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
        <set-backend-service base-url="{{BaseURL}}" />
        
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

It should be able to work with POST request as well. But i get 500 internal server error for POST

Comment: where did you specify the APIM policy ? make sure it's used in the global config

Comment: Its added in inboud policy in Azure portal

Comment: yes but there are many layers, you can define policy at global level, or per route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the same policy in my POST request and got expected response.

**Policy I have used**-

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>**********</audience>
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>https://sts.windows.net/{tenant_Id}/</issuer>
            </issuers>
            <required-claims>
                <claim name="aud" match="all">
                    <value>**********</value>
                </claim>
            </required-claims>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

**Output**-

[image]

[image]

**Trace**-

[image]

If you are still receiving 500 internal server error then I would suggest you to check the step where it is failing with the help of  **trace**.

Comment: Thanks i tried the same with some dummy project it worked, i will have to add more logs . Problem seems to be somewhere else